# Disable/re-enable button within isolate scope directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I need to enable/disable a button after click with Angular. When a user clicks "Submit form", it makes an `http` request. If an error occurs (inside the `catch`), I want to re-enable the directive button so that a user can try again. I have a directive with `controllerAs` syntax and `isolateScope`. Below is the code I have (simplified for here);

**`myCtrl` parent controller (controllerAs is `myCtrl`)**

```
    vm.submit = function() {
      MyService
        .update()
        .then(function(res) {
          // success
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          vm.error = true;
          // error
        });
    };
```

**Parent view with `my-form` directive**

```
<my-form form-submit='myCtrl.submit()'></my-form>
```

**`myForm` Directive**

```
  function myForm() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'myform.html',
      scope: {
        formSubmit: '&',
      },
      require: ['form', 'myForm'],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        var formCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var directiveCtrl = ctrls[1];

        scope.isButtonDisabled = false;

        scope.submit = function() {
          scope.submitted = true;
          directiveCtrl.submit();
        };
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var vm = this;

        // Submit parent function
        vm.submit = function() {
          vm.formSubmit();
        };
      },
      controllerAs: 'myFormCtrl',
      bindToController: true
    };
  }

  angular.module('mymodule')
    .directive('myForm', [ myForm ]);
```

**`myForm` directive template**

```
<form name='myForm' novalidate>
    // form fields
    <button ng-click='submit()' ng-disabled='isButtonDisabled'>Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the promise resolved in the parent controller, you could just pass the promise back to the child controller and handle the logic there.  Something like this should work:

parent:

```
vm.submit = function() {
  return MyService.update().$promise;
};
```

child:

```
vm.submit = function() {
      vm.formSubmit().then(function(res) {
      // success
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      vm.error = true;
      // error
      scope.isButtonDisabled = false;
    });
}
```